# How do i fix this "call_user_func_array()" error

Tags: array, parameter

Please, somebody, help me out.. How do I fix this?

I kept on receiving this each time I tried to register an account and create a subsite on the frontend of my WordPress multisite

`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in /var/www/u0851948/public_html/**.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289`

**Below is what i have on line 289;**

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an `add_action` or `add_filter` hook is does not have a correct callback function. Usually, in my cases anyway, this is because of a minor misspelling in the function name when adding the hook. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to pinpoint the issue from this warning alone.

Comment: Please check the question again... Thanks @Howdy_McGee

Comment: Is `$the_['function']` a valid callable function that accepts parameters?

Comment: Yes @Howdy_McGee

Comment: Everything was working fine earlier today. I don't know what happened..

**Could it be a plugin?**

Comment: Well, given the PHP warning it sounds like either the function is not a callable function ( maybe a class method? ) or the `array_slice()` is not returning an array of exactly 2 items.

Comment: It could be a plugin or it could be a theme. You'll need to disable all the plugins and revert to a default theme to know for sure.

Comment: Ok. Let me quickly do that. Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks. It worked!